# Append HTML Including ng-repeat directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, jquery-append

I'm trying to append an alert class that includes the angular ng-repeat directive:

```
ng-repeat="m in orders.messages"
```

The html appends fine, but the angular does not bind. It simply displays one alert with {{m}} as the contents. When I check Google Developer tools, it includes the directive as well. Also, when I put the static html instead of appending it, it repeats as expected.

```
var validationErrors = '<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert" ng-repeat="m in order.messages"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button><strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span> Warning!</strong> {{ m }} </div>';

$('#errorMessage').append(validationErrors);
```

Is there a way to append this so that the angular binds?

Comment: can you provide a fiddler?

Comment: i just found the $compile service which fixes it, actually